# is /. and / same in go? Period(.) as id is not recognised

Tags: go, net-http, get-request

I have two route handlers

`v1Router. Path("/{id}"). Methods(http.MethodGet). Handler(r.getter())`

`v1Router. Path("/"). Methods(http.MethodGet). Handler(r.searcher())`

when i am sending request at /"some id" it is working as expected ,but when i am sending request at /. the request is going through second handler.

Can anyone explain the above behaviour?

when i am sending request at /"some id" it is working as expected ,but when i am sending request at /. the request is going through second handler.

Answer (score 3):

It's mentioned in the documentation for the `net/http` package, underneath `http.ServeMux` — though it's easy to miss.

Ref: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#hdr-Request_sanitizing

Source: https://go.dev/src/net/http/server.go?s=40985:41006#L2450

Single and double periods are stripped from the route.

Answer (score -1):

> is /. and / same in go?

No, they aren't. Especially not as an URL path.

Comment: Do you any explanation for above behaviour ,why Period(.) is not recognised as id ,why the call is going to / endpoint not /{id}